# why span element is displaying as block level element?

Tags: jquery

I just read [this](http://api.jquery.com/add/) and found

```
$( "p" ).clone().add( "<span>Again</span>" ).appendTo( document.body );
```

But could not understand why `span` element is displaying as a block level element really.

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GnN4q/)

Comment: It's not.. The `<p>`'s are doing what they are supposed to do.

Comment: it is not added as a block level element http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/AZyN2/1/

Comment: What makes you think it's displaying as a block? I don't see that.

Comment: oh! its my mistake to understand just realised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `span` is an inline element by default.

What is a block element in your example is the paragraph `p` element. Which is causing the span to be added under it as the paragraph is taking all the width of the page.

Take a look at this debug image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The span element is inline at all look here

```
alert($('body').css('span'));
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/GnN4q/1/)